# achartengine zoom and black border

Tags: android, graph, achartengine

I'm adding graphics to my application using achartengine but I have some doubts.
Is there any way to remove the black frame that surrounds the chart and put it transparent? is that right now the bottom of the chart if I have the edge transparent but not how to set it.
The other question is, how I can set a zoom into a graph?, as it will always appear that bars certain (in my case 3).

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can set the color of the chart margins:

```
mRenderer.setMarginsColor(color);
```

You can hide the margins by calling:

```
mRenderer.setMargins(new double[] {0, 0, 0, 0});
```

You can also hide the legend:

```
mRenderer.setShowLegend(false);
```

Pinch zoom is enabled by default. In order to enable the zoom buttons:

```
mRenderer.setZoomButtonsVisible(true);
```

I don't understand your last sentence. Please create another question with details.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
renderer.setMarginsColor(resources.getColor(R.color.white));
renderer.setBackgroundColor(resources.getColor(R.color.white));
```